# How many instances of String will be created?

Tags: java, string, instance

The result of this code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Java";
        s.concat(" SE 6");
        s.replace('6', '7');
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

will be `"Java"`
Who can tell me how many instances of String will be created during execution?

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java. I believe three

Comment: @WalkerRandolphSmith actually 4, you're creating 2 new strings at `s.concat(" SE 6");` the resulting `"Java SE 6"` and the `" SE 6"`

Comment: `concat` and `replace` returns new stirngs, and you already have `"Java"` and `" SE 6"` strings.

Comment: stop minusing my question lol

Comment: @JordiCastilla good catch. I didn't think about that.

Comment: @RuslanLomov this is one of the tipical questions in SO, you have every day a *how many strings will be created here???*, with *why this overriden method is not getting called??* joined to *how to parse this date with format `xxxxYYYYzzzz`???* if you don't make a research expect downvotes

Comment: It almost certainly depends on the internal implementation of `replace`...

Comment: It also depends whether the optimizer is smart enough to determine that the `concat` and `replace` calls can be optimized away.  And the internal implementation of `print` and the output stack

Comment: And it what you mean by "during execution".

Comment: there are always people that will point you somewhere else but not with the help answer! Too much ambitions i would say.If you don't understand the question or if you don't want to answer it just skip it. Don't tell other people what they should do, it is there own choice.Thanks alot to the people that make their sentence to help resolve a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String is immutable in Java. Though you are invoking methods on it, they returns a new string each time.

There are 4 instance created here in this case

Please follow the comments:

```
    String s = "Java";   // 1
    s.concat(" SE 6");   // 2 & 3 for concat method returns a new string  and  another literal created " SE 6"
    s.replace('6', '7'); // 4 returns a new string instance  which you are not receiving
    System.out.print(s);
```

Comment: Statements never cause string literals to be instantiated. They are pre-existing.